# Matching codes in an array with the things in a select-list (javascript, json)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've been trying to make a list of "codes" (which I get from a .json file), that can be selected in a drop-down list. If to click on one of the codes, it should turn a hidden div into visible, showing additional information. What causes me a problem is that when I try to match a option value in the list with the matching code, it can't seem to match. (I have a feeling it might be because it can't find the values in the array I made for the codes.)

```
<script>
    var codesArray = [];

    function ajax_get_results() {

        var results = document.getElementById("results");
        var select = document.getElementById("code");
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("GET", "ainekood_pohiandmed.json", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                results.innerHTML = "";
                // <div id="results"> - Should show this in the div!
                results.innerHTML = "<b>"+data[0].ainekood+"</b></br>"+data[0].aineNimi+" (<i>"+data[0].courseName+"</i>)</br>EAP: "+data[0].eap+"</br>Hindamisviis: "+data[0].hindamisviis+"</br>Semester: "+data[0].semester+"</br>Oppejoud: "+data[0].ppejud+"</hr>";
                // Adds the codes into the Select-form
                for(var obj in data){
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    var code = data[obj].ainekood;
                    opt.value = code;
                    opt.innerHTML = code;
                    select.appendChild(opt);
                    // Adds the codes into the array
                    codesArray.push(code);
                }
                // Gets all of the codes
                //console.log(codesArray);
            }
        }
        hr.send(null);
        results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
        // Doesn't get any codes from here...
        //console.log(codesArray);
    }

    // This doesn't work...
    function expandDivs(elem) {
        for(var code in codesArray){
            if(elem.value == codesArray[code]){
                document.getElementById('results').style.display = "block";
                console.log("Match found: "+elem.value+" EQUALS "+codesArray[code]);
            }else{
                document.getElementById('results').style.display = "none";
                console.log("No matches found");
            }
        }
    }

    // Manually comparing works
    function expandDiv(elem) {
        if(elem.value == "AIA6010" || elem.value == "AIA6020"){
            document.getElementById('results').style.display = "block";
            console.log("Match found: "+elem.value);
        }else{
            document.getElementById('results').style.display = "none";
            console.log("No matches found");
        }
    }
</script>
```

All of the code - http://pastebin.com/YfQ21qTg

Comment: Your `codesArray` is an array like `['code1', 'code2', 'code3']`. Value of the select is also `code1`. When you go `codesArray['code1']`, you'll get undefined. and false match.

Answer (score 0):

The 'for' you're using is to scroll keys in an object, it won't work for arrays. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

But there is a javascript function that allows to check what you  want without having to scroll your array. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Like this:

```
if(codesArray.indexOf(elem.value) != -1){ //if element is in array, it'll return the index of the element in array, or -1 if it's not in the array.

   var match_index = codesArray.indexOf(elem.value)
   document.getElementById('results').style.display = "block";
   console.log("Match found: "+elem.value+" EQUALS "+codesArray[match_index]);

   } else {

   document.getElementById('results').style.display = "none";
   console.log("No matches found");
  }
```